# What will my grandson see?

Tags: near-future, earth, climate-change

It’s the year 2109, despite the efforts of the heroic climate change campaigners of my childhood the tide of human progress was too much to halt. Humanity didn’t change its ways and everything happened the way the scientists warned that it would.

Sea levels have risen, animals have gone extinct, and our lives are now nothing like they were when I was a child in 2019.

I’ve seen hundreds of alternative earth questions here but I don’t believe this one has been asked? Assuming that the majority view on climate change is accurate and that humanity fails to change its ways. How will human life be different in 90 years time?

Comment: Even the scientists have different views on how the climate change will go, without putting in the skepticals or negationists. I am afraid this cannot be objectively answered.

Comment: read the first several chapters of Ready Player One, that is a pretty accurate account.

Comment: Here's what the Earth looked like at 5-8 degrees warmer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldLBoErAhz4

Answer (score 1):

According to median IPCC models barely noticeable difference for a random observer:

- plus 2-3 C (most of the increase during nights, winters and near poles)
- less than meter higher ocean level
- clearly more heat waves, with other extreme climate events the models are unclear, but they are likely

If for story reasons you need some doom, then I suggest picking some barely sticking out of an ocean island. Or area, where rain pattern clearly changed (AFAIK, in Europe: Spain and Portugal is going to be much drier). You may also mention ships going from Europe to China through Northern Sea Route. If you go with extreme emissions scenarios, then you have another story problem - it assumes an industrial boom in third world, that would be mostly based on coal. (which means still a great improvement for Africa)

The problem is that with current trends continue, we would clearly mess with climate, while having much more powerful technology and becoming much richer. You presumably would get people that would be on average affluent by AD 2019 first world standards, would have life expectancy of much over 100 years, waste time in virtual reality, are designer babies, have GMO pet, are being served by AI... oh and by occasion they run air conditioning, as the climate indeed become annoying.

Comment: And, since we are currently well  under the "median" models, by more than three sigma, maybe even those predictions are over stating things.

Comment: The real wildcard is fusion power coming online in 2050. Having an unlimited source of power for water desalination, air conditioning and growing crops with artificial lights in greenhouses run by robots really changes things.

Comment: @SurprisedDog Hard to say, already with fission plants we have theoretically cheap fuel (per kWh) and but initial investment is quite high. While fusion as game changer is possible, I'd not rule out simpler ideas like some serially produced nuclear reactors or starting covering deserts with some cheap solar panels.

Comment: @puppetsock I know that something like a decade ago there was serious reduction of estimates. I'm not aware of any serious recent adjustment, so if you have, please link me the data.

Comment: You are seriously underestimating the effect of 2-3 C warming. It might be true that for the life of the typical western city dweller the direct consequences are minor. But 2-3 C change seriously messes with agriculture and will make a large proportion of current farm land not suitable for whatever is grown there now. If global food production drops 10% below normal in 1 year, you are going to see a lot of starving kids on tv. If that happens 10 years in row, you will see a lot of starving kids in front of you house.

Comment: @quarague Technically speaking mild AGW means in higher latitudes higher yields through longer vegetation season and boosted photosynthesis through higher CO2 levels. Setting this aside, are you suggesting that it is beyond technological or intellectual capabilities of farmers in my country to plant sun loving corn instead of potatoes?

Answer (score -1):

This is not my expertise, but I used to be climate skeptic as a teenager(yeah, I know, I'm sorry, I was a teenager, ok? kek), who later actually sat down and read a bit about it, so I'll tell you what I understood. Climate change is actually much slower of an extintion effect than most media and activists would have you believe. From what I've learned, it's better to compare it to an old stream train - it starts to move slowly, but it's very very hard to stop.

Activists might be doing it out of goodwill, but their overestimation/misunderstanding often leads to deniers getting ammunition such as "see, you said this would happen, and it didn't, so climate change is nonsense". As for media, I will not assume their misinformation is out of a goodwill, they're doing it for cash, and the fact is that they're making the waters murky and more confusing with their BS.

---

So, by 2109, the changes might still not be that serious. I mean, they'll be serious, but not to the point of immediate extinction. You can expect not very numerous, but extremely potent hurricanes, stronger than nowadays. You can expect around 50cm to 2m rising sea levels. Nearby equator, deserts will start to appear/expand. And in the areas away from the equator, you can expect weather to be going crazy every now and then.

As for the largest problem, I'd say that'd be drinkable water. Humanity will have to start desalinating sea water for drinking, because drinkable water will become scarce. Sadly, it's unlikely that poorer countries will have resources to do that, so you can expect lots of wars over the water sources in Africa, as well as refugees fleeing from there, and many, many people dying.

The thing is, it doesn't sound THAT bad. It's not an extinction event. It's really bad, but not as bad as media and activists would have you think.

But problem is, 2109 isn't where it ends. It's where it starts. By 2109, if we do not stop poluting, we will have crossed the point of no return. It's called [feedback loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_change_feedback#Positive), and it's kinda like that train I talked about - before you cross it, you might still stop it, but once you cross it, it's only gonna get faster and faster.

It means that when our effect is too pronounced, the effect the climate change has caused will return feedback where it starts amplifying itself, by dozens of various proceses. In some areas, under the eternaly frozen ground, there are tons of methane, which will escape into the atmosphere. Rainforests will grow drier, forest fires, decrease in earths albedo(reflectivity), it will reach point where even if we stop poluting and leave the Earth, climate change will no longer stop, and it will likely be out of our possibilities to do anything to change that. And by 2300s-2500s, we might really start talking about true extinction event. Large areas of the Earth might become uninhabitable deserts.

The effect of that will not be eternal. Assuming humans completely leave the Earth, in about 1000 or 2000 years, situation will recover back to normal(not really, but acceptably close to normal). Extinct species won't recover, but surviving ones will start to adapt to new niches and much much later, fill their roles.

---

As I said I am not a scientist and this is only my understanding of what it might be like. If there's anything wrong about my understanding, I'd welcome to be corrected.

Comment: For starter, I'd recommend potholer54's series about climate change: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=52KLGqDSAjo&list=PL82yk73N8eoX-Xobr_TfHsWPfAIyI7VAP

It's a good entertaining introductory series to help one start orient themselves in problematic of Climate Change.

Comment: Not a bad summary. Might want to mention ocean acidification and the probable collapse of fisheries (which will likely result from the *combination* of overfishing *and* climate change together).

Comment: I'd recommend not bothering with potholer54. He's not very knowledgeable. Tends to stick to the Al Gore line like he watched Gore's movie and nothing else.

Comment: Population in developed world is stable or decreasing, while all extra billions are being born in the third world. Even if we assume that they are indeed reaching carrying capacity of their environment, why are you pointing out "climate" as reason for their migration towards richer countries?

Comment: @Shadow1024 Because of effects such as increased storm frequency and intensity, as well as desertification of farmland, more regular and intense droughts, diminishing supply of fresh water... All of these things are effectively reducing carrying capacity in *addition* to the growth of populations. Both are factors in what is happening.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII Look at the official UN estimates please and tell me whether slight decrease in carrying capacity could make any noticeable difference in overall picture: http://www.cairco.org/sites/default/files/images/charts/un-africa-population-projections-steve-sailer-2-1000w.gif https://www.pewresearch.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/FT_19.06.17_WorldPopulation_Populiation-growth-Africa-projected-remain-strong.png